Are apples 25% air?
There are numerous articles online [1][2][3][4][5]][6] claiming that apples float because they are 25% air by volume. The air is claimed to be trapped in or between the cells of the flesh of the fruit. I know that there is often a space around the seeds in the core of the apple. I don't think this void is what is being talked about here. After all, the void around the seeds could not reasonably be claimed to be 25% of the volume of the fruit.
I am skeptical of this claim because 25% is a suspiciously round number. Also many things are less dense than water without being air. None of these websites cites a reputable source.

I found this excellent paper which investigated exactly this measurement for a Braeburn apple:
Lazar Dražeta, Alexander Lang, Alistair J. Hall, Richard K. Volz, Paula E. Jameson, Air volume measurement of ‘Braeburn’ apple fruit, Journal of Experimental Botany, Volume 55, Issue 399, 1 May 2004, Pages 1061–1069, https://doi.org/10.1093/jxb/erh118

"A range of techniques has been developed to measure intercellular air in apple fruit. One is based on weighing the volume of water that replaces an equal volume of air removed by a vacuum from a submerged sample. A number of studies have used this principle with a range of sampling methods, vacuum pressures, treatment durations, and infiltration media (Reeve, 1953; Harker and Ferguson, 1988; Vincent, 1989; Rajapakse et al., 1990; Yamaki and Ino, 1992; Yearsley et al., 1996). By contrast, Calbo and Sommer (1987) estimated intercellular air volume using a gasometric technique that measured the amount of air extracted from samples when subjected to vacuum. An alternative way to calculate air fraction has been to assess the weight and volume of a whole fruit when immersed in water (Bain and Robertson, 1951; Skene, 1966; Westwood et al., 1967; Baumann and Henze, 1983; Hatfield and Knee, 1988; Harker and Hallett, 1992; Tu et al., 1996; Harker et al., 1999). Other authors have taken a stereological approach to estimate air volume (Soudain and Phan Phuc, 1979; Ruess and Stösser, 1993; Goffinet et al., 1995). However, estimates of air volume in apples in the studies above ranged widely (c. 2.5–41%).
...
In the cortex, the air fraction first increased from a subepidermal level of about 18%, to reach a peak of about 23% in the layer just beneath. It then felt steadily to about 12% at the core line. Here, at the boundary between cortex and pith, a sharp discontinuity occurred with the air fraction rising suddenly to about 15% before falling steadily again to about 7% at the centre of the fruit. "

In summary, depending on the location in the fruit, Braeburn apples contain 7-23% air. Other studies show a range from 2.5-41%. 25% falls within this range.
